# Find object with best matching subcategory

Tags: c#

I have  `string articleId = "3.1.2.4.2015"` The last number `2015` represents the article's ID, the numbers before it represents the groups and sub-groups of the article. For example that article is in group `3`,  subgroup `1`, sub-sub-group `2`, and sub-sub-sub-group `4`. 
I have the following class:

```
public class CustDiscount
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Group{ get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

And a list of `CustDiscount` objects `List<CustDiscount> listCustDisc;` if in that `listCustDisc` I have the following objects

```
listCustDisc[0].Group = 3.1
listCustDisc[0].Discount = 5
listCustDisc[1].Group = 3
listCustDisc[1].Discount = 2
listCustDisc[2].Group = 1.2.4
listCustDisc[2].Discount = 8
```

I have to get the `listCustDisc` object with `Group` which best matches `articleId` at the beginning. In the example above I have to get `listCustDisc[0]`. How can I do that?

The number of sub-groups for article is `13` maximum. The method doesn't have to consider the last number `2015`.

Comment: What is "articleId"; is that the same as "the number of the article"? How does something "best match articleId"? Numeric distance? [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)? By lexicographical order of its prefix (sub-)*categories? Please be more specific; you could give an example of desired output.

Comment: `articleId` is the string I mentioned in the beggining of my question. For example if I have `articleId = 3.1.2.4.2015` and I have `listCustDisc[0].Group = 3.1 ,listCustDisc[1].Group = 3.1.2 ,listCustDisc[2].Group = 3  , listCustDisc[3].Group = 2.5` . The one which best matches `articleId` is `listCustDisc[1]` we start the comparation from the beggining and doesn't consider the last number `2015` Numeric distance not lexicographical , I will have only numbers for Group.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to get `listCustDisc` object with `Group` which best matches `articleId`

So you've got an article with an id of `1.2.3.456` and a list of customer discounts, and you're trying to find the one with most sub-categories in common with a given article. You might start by determining how well a discount group matches a given articleId by counting the depth at which the sub-categories match.

**Edit:** Changed `MatchesAtDepth` so the full discount group is required to match. This means a DiscountGroup of `1.2.345` does not apply for a product with ID `1.2.678`.

```
public static int MatchesAtDepth(string discountGroup, string articleId) {
    string[] dg = discountGroup.Split(new[] { '.' });
    string[] aid = articleId.Split(new[] { '.' });

    if (dg.Length > aid.Length) {
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dg.Length; i++) {
        if (dg[i] != aid[i]) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return dg.Length;
}
```

You could then perform a linear search of the list and keep track of the discount that most closely matches the category:

```
public static CustDiscount FindMostSpecificDiscount(IEnumerable<CustDiscount> discounts, Article article) {
    CustDiscount best = null;
    int bestScore = 0;
    foreach (CustDiscount discount in discounts) {
        int score = MatchesAtDepth(discount.Group, article.Id);
        if (score > bestScore) {
            best = discount;
            bescScore = score;
        }
    }
    return best;
}
```

Since `bestScore` is initialized to `0`, the discount group must have some part of the category in common.

But what if you have two discounts; one for group `1.2` with a discount of 20%, and one for group `1.2.3` with a discount of 15%. Then an article with an Id of `1.2.3.456` would get the 15% rebate; depending on how discounts are structured, this might be right or wrong.

If you have *a lot* of `CustDiscount`s, consider building a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) over your sub-categories (e.g. like [`kpol/trie`](https://github.com/kpol/trie)) which will make the average lookup proportional to the average category depth instead of half the number of discounts.

Comment: And if my `articleId = 3.1.2.2041` and in `discounts` variable that I pass to the method `FindMostSpecificDiscount` for `discounts.Group` there is neither `3.1` neither `3.1.2` neither anything that starts with `3` then the method will return `null`,  right?

Comment: @ProfileForStack4: Yes. You may want to express discount as a non-nullable type and present a default zero discount for completeness, though. Also, the fact that a discount can contain both a price and a discount (and a customer ID?) seems a bit faulty?

Comment: I pass to function  `FindMostSpecificDiscount` `articleId = 2.1.401` and `IEnumerable<CustDiscount> discounts` , `discounts` list contains `150` objects , none of them has `discount.Group = 2.  or discount.Group = 2.1 or discount.Group = 2.1.401` nevertheless the function returns the first object of the list which has `discount.Group = 2.1.9911` . How should I change both functions `FindMostSpecificDiscount` and `MatchesAtDepth` to return `null` in my case or `discount` objects if there are some matches?

Comment: @ProfileForStack4: I've changed the `MatchesAtDepth` function so it returns -1 if the discount group isn't fully a prefix of the article ID.